# Center drawable and scale height

Tags: android, imageview, scale, android-view

Since I want to support tablets and smartphones without delivering a special "HD" version, I need to scale my Images depending on the resolution of the users device. This is the ImageView source that looks good on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus:

```
  <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/character"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                       android:src="@drawable/ma_un1_001" />
```

[image]

But it will cut the image on the nexus 7.
[image]

When I changed the width and height to:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/character"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ma_un1_001" />
```

Unfortunately this scales the image out of the view:
[image]

changing the xml to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Would still cut the image.

So I changed the scaleType to FIT_START

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/character"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/ma_un1_001" />
```

[image]

Looks great on all my devices, but the drawable is aligned to the left. 
Is there any way to center it?

Comment: Have you tried all the `scaleType`?

Comment: yes. FitEnd for example will align the drawable to the right

Comment: If none of the scaleType fits you, I will say scale down the image programmatically to the screen height and width. Not difficult to do it.

Comment: after I noticed fitEnd moved the drawable to the right, I tried this configuration using fitCenter and it seems to work. Thank you. Post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think you can post the answer by yourself, since you solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wenhui I found the solution.

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/character"
                **android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"**
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                **android:scaleType="fitCenter"**
                android:src="@drawable/ma_un1_001" />
```

Scales the Image to every screensize and won't cut anything. Thank you very much.