# layout_height should be a function of layout_width

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview

Assuming portrait mode, I have an ImageView who's image will be of variable size (yet always square). I would like the ImageView's width to always be equal to the layout's width (fill_parent) and as you can see the scaleType is "centerCrop" which will scale.

The problem is that if I set the *layout_height* also to "fill_parent" then, being that centerCrop retains the original aspect ratio, the height takes precedence and the image is cropped on the left and right. (this of course assumes a screen that is taller than it is wide). However, if I set the layout_height to "wrap_content", then the height is no longer scaled and I end up with a cropped rectangle. It does this because it respects the original height of the image.

Is there a layout_height setting that will give precedence to a layout_width of "fill_parent"?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_image"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_album" />
```

Removing the android:layout_height attribute causes a crash:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Setting android:layout_height="0dp" crushes the image vertically.

Answer: Using a combination of responses from other users, I was able to find a simple solution that works well for me.

First, the image view has this configuration (note the *fitStart*):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_album"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_album" />
```

Then programmatically, a small modification to the height of the image to match the width (within Activity.onResume())

```
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_album);
        boolean bPost = iv.post(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_album);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)iv.getLayoutParams();
                        params.width = ASong.this.findViewById(R.id.song_view_layout_top).getWidth();
                        params.height = params.width;                           
                        iv.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                });

        if (bPost == false)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("runnable not posted");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with this issue yesterday. This is the XML that solved my problem:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/character"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ma_un1_001" />
```

see thread here: [Center drawable and scale height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297939/center-drawable-and-scale-height)

To cut a long story short:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but it still doesn't solve my problem. This is because the ImageView will still fill the entire screen, even though it's associated image is sized correctly. This results in pushing any subsequent controls off the screen.

Comment: What about wrapping your imageview? Do you wan't to create something like a thumb gallery? In this case it could be better to create thumbs. You could scale them as you wish and you wouldn't have to do layout-magic. Beside this would increase the performance and it would also avoid memory related problems.

Comment: The problem with a wrapping the IV without programmatically setting the size is that the height of the container is too short when layout_height=wrap_content and takes up the remainder of the height when layout_height=fill_parent.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do it programmatically:

Surround the ImageView with a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_below="@id/header"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_image"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_album" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in your onCreate(), insert

```
findViewById(R.id.container).post(
    new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)container.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = params.width;
        container.setLayoutParams(params);
    }}
);
```

The code must be into post() because the main process can't directly modify the layout structure.

Comment: I'd preffer to use fitCenter. The height is variable yet always a square in this case, but **params.height = params.width;** will be problematic in case he wants to change the shape of the image. **fitCenter** will work with any shape.

Comment: @vallero. this got me started thanks! FYI. it's not necessary to call container.setLayoutParams(params) because modification of the params takes direct effect. Secondly, The width was -1 meaning (fill-parent) so instead I used the width of the view instead. These view dimensions weren't available until the runnable was called, but fyi3, this is the main thread too (gui).